# How do you shuffle an array in Coffeescript?

Tags: algorithm, coffeescript, shuffle

How do you shuffle an array in Coffescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) from [github](https://gist.github.com/ddgromit/859699) (modified):

```
fisherYates = (arr) ->
    i = arr.length
    return arr unless i > 0

    while --i
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1))
        [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]] # use pattern matching to swap
```

Comment: Strange to return `false` instead of `arr` in the empty case.

Comment: @RoyJ true, changed that

Comment: If you want to be concise, I'd prefer `return arr unless i > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your form, when I tested, gave me an unexpected behavior.
This way worked for me.

```
shuffle_array = (arr) ->
i = arr.length

while --i
  j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1))
  [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]]

return arr unless i > 0
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array::shuffle = ->
    a=@
    i=a.length
    while i>0
        int=Math.floor(Math.random()*i)
        i--
        o=a[i]
        a[i]=a[int]
        a[int]=o
    a

console.log([1..10].shuffle())
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation around your answer?  Even adding some comments would be a start.